# Element switch by fadeIn/fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the line of codes below to fadeOut the form with the class ".quote" and replace it with the DIV that has the class ".thanks." when the button is clicked. it only works when you click on the input area but doesn't fadein `div.thanks`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".quote, .thanks").click(function(){
    $('form:fadeIn(:.thanks)').fadeOut (5000);
  }); 

});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.thanks {
    display: hide;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="get" id="quote" class="quote">
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
    </label>
  </p>
</form>
<div class="thanks">Thanks for contacting us, we'll get back to you as soon as posible</div><!-- End thanks -->
```

I'd also like to know how to make it get the visitors name and insert it in `div.thanks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
$(".quote").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(5000, function(){
        $(".thanks").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Dz1: You're trying to add what's called a "comment", not an "edit". Use "add comment" to comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS to position both elements in the same location. Typically this involves using position:absolute and setting left: and right: CSS styles. Once that's set up correctly, you can use jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut as you expect.

Comment: NexxeuS with your Idea I changed it to $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".quote").click(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(5000);
 $(".thanks").fadeIn(6000);

  }); 
  
}); and it now works. But I want it to work when the button is clicked and not the input field. I also want it to get the vistor's name and insert it in the .thanks DIV